# NSMutableArray initWithCapacity failing

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, init

I'm trying to initialize an NSMutableArray and it's not working correctly. Subsequent access to the array throws an exception saying "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array." A breakpoint following the initialization line says that my array has a location in memory, but that it has 0 objects

Here's my attempt at the moment:

in my .h

```
@interface SomeInterface : NSObject 
{
@private
    NSMutableArray *myArr;
}
```

in my .m

```
- (id) initWithHeight: (int) height
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self->myArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:height];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The breakpoint shows myArr = (NSMutableArray *) 0x######## 0 objects

Does anyone know how to properly initialize an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initWithCapacity:` does not create objects in your array, so the debugger isn't lying - your array is empty until you add objects to it, either by using `addObject:` or by initializing it with objects in the first place.

Comment: i just found this in the class reference:
Note that NSArray objects are not like C arrays. That is, even though you specify a size when you create an array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0. This means that you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2. Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds; if you try to add an object at index 3 (when the size of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an exception.

Comment: solved: i was drawing the index error because i tried to use replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject. This didn't work considering that the array was still empty. insertObject:atIndex permits access to the next open index, as specified in the class reference above.

Comment: Yep. That `insertObject:atIndex:` would work as well.
But you should probably just use `addObject:` unless you are not adding them in order.

Answer (score 1):

as yonix pointed you are not creating any objects, here an example that adds your object:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Ssuti : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableArray *_myArr;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *myArr;

- (id) initWithHeight: (int) height;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "Ssuti.h"


@implementation Ssuti

@synthesize myArr = _myArr;


- (void)dealloc {
     [super dealloc];
}

- (id) initWithHeight: (int) height
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.myArr = [NSMutableArray array];

        [self.myArr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:height]];

        NSLog(@"myArr :: %@", self.myArr);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

then in the ViewController you call it:

```
Ssuti *mySssuti = [[Ssuti alloc]initWithHeight:345];

    [mySssuti release];
```

;)